How to export / import my Android Jetpack-Compose app's Room SQLite Database?
I have several jetpack-compose-based android applications, that use Room to store all its data.
Is there any way to export / import my database as a .sqlite file?

This is not really related too much to Compose, other than perhaps how you get the location to backup/export to. There has been material already written about this, such as this chapter of this free book of mine.

Thx!  I'll check it out.

Not much different from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/79036892/549372.

Here's a way to do this in jetpack compose, that also can export and import to and from a backup zip file.
I've created a library to help with this: https://github.com/dessalines/room-db-export-import
Much thanks to this answer.
It requires Zip4J in your build.gradle :
implementation 'net.lingala.zip4j:zip4j:2.11.5'
This goes into your Room abstract class:
private const val DB_NAME = "com.MY_APP"

data class DbFiles(
    val dbFile: File,
    val walFile: File?,
    val shmFile: File?,
    val backupZipFile: File?,
)

private fun dbFiles(ctx: Context) =
    DbFiles(
        dbFile = ctx.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME),
        walFile = File(ctx.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).path + "-wal"),
        shmFile = File(ctx.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).path + "-shm"),
        backupZipFile = File(ctx.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).path + ".zip"),
    )

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
fun backupDatabase(
    ctx: Context,
    backupFileUri: Uri,
) {
    try {
        val dbFiles = dbFiles(ctx)
        checkpoint()

        // Create a backup zip file
        ZipFile(dbFiles.backupZipFile).addFiles(listOf(dbFiles.dbFile, dbFiles.walFile, dbFiles.shmFile))

        // Copy the tmp file to the other one
        val os = ctx.contentResolver.openOutputStream(backupFileUri)!!
        Files.copy(dbFiles.backupZipFile?.toPath(), os)
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
fun restoreDatabase(
    ctx: Context,
    backupFileUri: Uri,
    restart: Boolean = true,
) {
    try {
        val dbFiles = dbFiles(ctx)

        // Delete the backup zip file first
        dbFiles.backupZipFile?.delete()

        // Copy the input file to the tmp file
        val inputStream = ctx.contentResolver.openInputStream(backupFileUri)!!
        Files.copy(inputStream, dbFiles.backupZipFile?.toPath())

        // Delete the other DB files
        dbFiles.dbFile.delete()
        dbFiles.walFile?.delete()
        dbFiles.shmFile?.delete()

        // Extract them
        ZipFile(dbFiles.backupZipFile).extractAll(dbFiles.dbFile.parent!!)
        checkpoint()
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

    if (restart) {
        val i = ctx.packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(ctx.packageName)
        i!!.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
        ctx.startActivity(i)
        exitProcess(0)
    }
}

private fun checkpoint() {
    val db = instance!!.openHelper.writableDatabase
    db.query("PRAGMA wal_checkpoint(FULL);")
    db.query("PRAGMA wal_checkpoint(TRUNCATE);")
}

To handle the file pickers:
val exportDbLauncher =
    rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.CreateDocument("application/zip"),
    ) {
        it?.also {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                AppDB.backupDatabase(ctx, it)
                Toast.makeText(ctx, dbSavedText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
...

onClick = {
    exportDbLauncher.launch("MY_APP_NAME")
}

val importDbLauncher =
    rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument(),
    ) {
        it?.also {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                AppDB.restoreDatabase(ctx, it, true)
                Toast.makeText(ctx, dbRestoredText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
...
onClick = {
    importDbLauncher.launch(arrayOf("application/zip"))
}

